# How to select first 2 <a> elements in table using css

Tags: css, css-selectors

How to select only the first two `a` elements in following table? I just want to select "Alle Filme" and "Generes"Alle Filme. That applies to "Alle Filme" but not "Genres".

```css
#menu-item-608 a,
#menu-item-587:first-child a {
  padding-top: 26px;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="head-main-nav">
  <div class="menu-genres-container">
    <ul id="main_header" class="main-header">
      <li id="menu-item-608" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-608"><a href="/?post_type=movies">Alle Filme</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-607" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-607">
        <a href="#">Genres</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-587" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-genres menu-item-587"><a href="/?genres=abenteuer">Abenteuer</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-588" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-genres menu-item-588"><a href="/?genres=action">Action</a></li>

        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not a table, that's a list-of-lists. Where's the `<table>`?

Comment: CSS doesn't have a `nth-descendant` selector, unfortunately - only `nth-child`.

Comment: Yes i mean in List of list

Comment: "I just want to select "Alle Filme" and GeneresAlle Filme" - I think you typoed or pasted that. Please reword your question. Did you mean to say "Abenteuer"?

Comment: Exact, i do not want to select "Abenteuer" but it selects wrongly. i want to select only Alle Filme" and Generes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ul#main_header > li:nth-child(1) > a,
ul#main_header > li:nth-child(2) > a {
    background-color: red;
}
```

The above CSS won't select "Abenteuer" nor "Action" because both of those are
2nd-degree descendants of the `<li>`, rather than immediate children of the `<li>`, whereas `>` is [the child combinator which only selects immediate children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator).

Answer (score 1):

Here is more easy example. you can select first two element by this code:

```
#menu-item-608 a:nth-child(-n+1), #menu-item-587 a:nth-child(-n+1){
padding-top: 26px;
font-size: 25px;
margin-bottom: 22px;
color:red;
```

}